# numpy large array to string gets

Tags: string, numpy

I have a numpy array of date objects from datetime, which I have to convert into a string so I can use it as part of a SQL statement (for mysql).  Generally, this works just fine:

```
dats = str(dates_list)
dats = string.replace(dats[1:-1],' ',"','")
```

except for when it's long enough that `print dates_list` shows the ... (ex: `print numpy.arange(4000)`).

I tried to directly use the **repr** special method (yeah, I know I shouldn't), which is supposed to provide a string representation that can be used to rebuild the object.  Clearly, I can't build this array using `[   0    1    2 ..., 4997 4998 4999]`.

How can I get a string representation of the entire aarray?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Converting to a list seems to work:

```
dats = str(list(dates_list))
```

But the more correct option is to change numpy's  [printoptions](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.set_printoptions.html). There is a `threshold` option that sets the limit to print a summary instead of the full repr. Default is 1000. You can change it to infinity:

```
import numpy as np
np.set_printoptions(threshold=np.inf)

dats = str(dates_list)
```